# How to Automatically redirect website IE browser to Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

Recently we migrated to latest version of application which allows the user to open application in any browser.

Earlier it use to support Only IE browsers.
After migration many users still open the application in old browser.

Since the application is very slow in IE browser.We are looking for a solution that will automatically open the URL/Login Page  in Chrome browser when user opens in IE browser.

i.e., when a user open URL in IE browser it automatically open the same URL in Google chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome Legacy Browser support allows this.  Under the "Hosts to open in Alternative Browser" policy, put in an entry for the site you want to force to open in Chrome, preceding it with an "!".  Example:
`!https://www.somesitetoopeninChromeonly.com.`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, the users open a page in IE and when they click an url on that page, it will open that URL in Chrome. 
I guess, you can't do this. You can use target="_blank" to open a new tab in the same browser.

If you want to open a link from an application in chrome and not in IE, you can change the default browser to chrome. Click on Start, type the "default app settings" and change the default browser to chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to let the user open Google Chrome manually by informing about it.

It is possible however, to make a document called "chrome.hta" for example, with the contents shown below, and then link to it on another page. (This will only work in Internet Explorer, not Edge)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
  var commandtoRun = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
  var website = "http://example.com/";
  oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, website, "", "open", "1");
  window.close();
</script>
```

The user now has to press "open" and "allow" after they click the link referring to the .hta file.

Now, on the page where you link to the .hta document, you can make the page detect the browser and adjust the link accordingly:

```
<a id="link" href="example.com">My Application</a>
<script>
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1))
    document.getElementById("link").href = "example.com/chrome.hta";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but we have two different solutions for this:

1. We use a javascript: link to use `ShellExecute` to run a small exe helper application that checks if Chrome is installed, and if it is, open Chrome to the URL parameter, optionally with switches (e.g. `--use-system-default-printer` and on shared logon PCs, `--incognito`). This requires configuring special permissions for the site in Internet Options|Security.
2. Now we can also use the `microsoft-edge:` protocol to open sites in Edge.

You could also install your own protocol for opening sites in Chrome but you would need a helper application to re-write the URL. I have one written to add `microsoft-edge-private:` to open links in Edge in InPrivate mode.

Answer (score 0):

To open the webpage in Microsoft Edge you can try the below code.

```html
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://stackoverflow.com"> TEST </a>
```