# How to redirect a particular link from IE to Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, redirect

if i open a link in IE then I need to check if IE is default browser or not, And if not, i need to redirect that link from IE to Chrome. Please  help me with the javascript code.

Comment: With which programming you want to try this scenario. Provide some details while posting query here. It will be helpful to get quick answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: I don't think you can detect whether the user is using default browser from javascript. Default browser has stuff dealing with registry, which if you can access with javascript would be a major security problem

Comment: @Pallavi Javascript

Comment: I don't think it is possible to open another browser from javascript.

Comment: @Manish, there is no api in javascript to check default browser, but you can navigate a link from ie to chrome (check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399702/how-to-automatically-redirect-website-ie-browser-to-chrome-browser). thank you

Comment: It can be a security concern for checking the default browser using JS. If you want to launch the URL from IE to chrome than you need to make registry entry. Than you can try to launch the URL in Chrome. Here is the link may give detailed information. https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2015/05/how-to-launch-a-url-in-google-chrome/